# Trouble converting normal sentences to pig latin

Tags: java

I'm trying to convert a sentence to pig latin but can't seem to get the correct output to work. For example the input 
    `the rain in spain stays mainly in the plain` yields an output of `ethay ethay ethay` with my current code whereas the expected output is `ethay ainray inay ainspay aysstay ainlymay inay ethay ainplay`

For those unfamiliar, the basic rules of pig latin are:

If the word begins with a consonant, take the beginning consonants up until the first vowel and move them to the end of the word. Then append ay at the very end. (so cricket would become icketcray)

If the word begins with a vowel, simply add ay to the end. (apple would become appleay)

If y is the first letter in the word, treat it as a consonant, otherwise it is used as a vowel. (young would become oungyay and system would become ystemsay)
My code is as follows:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PigLatin{
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String line = scan.next();
    String piglatin = translateSentence(line);
    System.out.println(piglatin);
}
public static String translateSentence(String line){
    for (int i =0; i < line.length(); i++ ) {
        char c = line.charAt(i);
        //for loop to analyze each word
        if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {

        //if (i <='a' || i<='A' || i>='z' || i>='Z'){
            String piglatin = translateword(line);                  
    return piglatin;    
        }
}
    return line; 
}


public static String translateword(String line) {
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int position = firstVowel(line);    
     String words = "";
     String output = "";
   for(int i = 0; i<line.length();i++){
      words = "";
        if (firstVowel(line) == 0) {
            words = line + "-way";

        } else if (firstVowel(line) == -1) {
            words = line + "";

         } else {        
            String first = line.substring(position);
            String second =  line.substring(0,position) + "ay";
            words = first + second;

        }       
   output = output + " " + words;
   //words = "";
   }
     return output;
}

public static int firstVowel(String line) {

    for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {

    if (line.charAt(i) == 'a' || line.charAt(i) == 'e'
        || line.charAt(i) == 'i' || line.charAt(i) == 'o'
        || line.charAt(i) == 'u') {

        return i;
    }
    }
    return -1;
}
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, thank you.

Comment: That's an awful lot of code. Where do you think the problem is? Normally the way you go about solving problems like this is by removing anything that isn't strictly necessary to reproduce the problem and focus on what's left. There's a lot of code in here left commented out, perhaps accidentally, and the indentation is a total wreck. Disorganized code is often buggy code as it's hard to see the mistakes. Keep things clean, *especially* if you're asking for help.

Comment: I only see one call to `scan.next()`, and the variable is poorly named `line` when it's only a single token. Did you mean `scan.nextLine()`, which actually reads one line of input?

Comment: You have two functions, translateSentence and translateword. Both of them you're passing in line. Why not split the sentence on spaces (and remove special characters for translateword's input) and then concatenate the results? Edit: by that I mean translateSentence splits the sentence into an array of words, words are looped through translateword (with the input being a single word) and then concatenate the results.

Comment: sorry @tadman, my spacing is correct in my IDE but it appears as though it got a bit messed up while trying to put it into a code block on stack overflow. sorry for the confusion, it's my first time posting

Comment: It looks like this boils down to a misunderstanding of how `for` works. If you `return` from within a `for` loop you return from the surrounding function. That code seems to expect that the inner `return` translates each word, but in fact that's the result for the whole sentence.

Comment: @RandyCamel It's not a big deal, but keep an eye on the preview to see how your question is going to look. Mixed tabs and spaces indenting is usually the case of stuff going seriously awry.

Comment: And right now, translateSentence is iterating per character, not per word (though still passing the entire line to translateword).

Answer (score 0):

first write a separate function to get list of words from line

```
public String[] getWords(String line) {
    String list[]=new String[100];
    int j=0;
    int end;
    end=line.indexOf(' ');

    while (end!=-1) {
        list[j]=line.substring(0, end);

        line=line.substring(end+1,line.length());
        j++;

        end=line.indexOf(' ');

    }
    list[j]=line.substring(0,line.length());

    return list;
}
```

then modify your translate line to call translate word multiple times, each time pass a single word.
Assuming your translateWord() returns a single correctly translated word. translateLine change in the following way:

```
if (Character.isAlphabetic(c)) {
    String wordList[]=getWords(line);
    String piglatin="";
    int i=0;
    while(!line[i].equals("")) {
        piglatin = piglatin+translateword(word[i]);
        i++;
    }                
    return piglatin;
}
```